# requestMapping annotation in controller head ，and thymeleaf static content will be not find

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

when I add requestmapping in controller,thymeleaf static content will be not find, such as

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/section")
public class SectionController {

@Autowired
private SectionService sectionService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/list")
public String listSection(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("result",sectionService.listSection());
    return "views/listSection";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveSection(Section section){
    sectionService.saveSection(section);
    return "redirect:/section/list";
}}
```

`listSection.html` using thymeleaf

```
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script th:src="@{jquery/jquery-3.2.1.js}" ></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script th:src="@{bootstrap/3.3.7v/js/bootstrap.js}"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link th:href="@{bootstrap/3.3.7v/css/bootstrap.css}" rel="stylesheet">
```

and start service like will report error static content will be not find
[chrome console report error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wupwx.png)

and I remove the requestMapping in controller class head, and access `http://localhost:9090/list`it worked as normal, please tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem is you are fetching static content with relative URL. Not from the absolute root path(`/`). So that for relative url it is requesting to the current URL's relative root path (Like for `/section/list` it will request to `/section/`+`path_of_your_content`) as `/section` is the root path of this URL. But when you try the URL like `/section` or `/list` it is requesting for content in `/` + `path_of_your_content` as `/` is the root path of this URL**

It the link URL is right, it should work if you make the URL from root. Change the `listSection.html` as following

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script th:src="@{/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.js}" ></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script th:src="@{/bootstrap/3.3.7v/js/bootstrap.js}"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link th:href="@{/bootstrap/3.3.7v/css/bootstrap.css}" rel="stylesheet">
```